# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in

Tags: php, magento, syntax

I am working on a dev server doing a Magento Install and integration with Web-to-Print solution PrintUI. The project uses several Magento extensions and I know integration can be a nightmare and support even worse (or non-existent) so I have been going slow and doing a lot of backups. I just installed Customer Menu Manager from Itoris and it took down the Magento Customer Accounts with this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in   /home/desynerx/public_html/magento/app/code/local/PrintUi/Design/controllers/AccountController.php on line 1
```

I know this code parses fine so I'm not sure exactly where to look. The rest of the site seems fine (http://desynerx.com/magento/). No response from Itoris and I have the rest of the weekend to get it back on line.

Any ideas where to look? Being a newbie kinda sucks but I've met some really cool people and I get to do what I love...

Comment: look at `/home/desynerx/public_html/magento/app/code/local/PrintUi/Design/controllers/AccountController.php` line 1?

Comment: You may need to add some more specific information to get an answer

Comment: If the file is clean, it might be an encoding issue ? For instance sometimes UTF8+Bom adds weird characters on top that cause errors on PHP scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the files are made for your system - if it has been developed on a windows machine it might has different lineendings which are incompatible with Linux - or the other way...

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. Do you think the culprit would be AccountController.php as this is the file referenced in the error? Can't re-saving the files correct the line endings if that is indeed the problem?

Comment: It bdepends on your editor... some will, some won't :/